# Force Download CSV File

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to create a button that will force a CSV file download but for some reason I am not able to get it working. This is the code that I have:

```
public function export_to_csv($result) {

$shtml="";

for ($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){

$shtml = $shtml.$result[$i]["order_number"]. "," .$result[$i]["first_name"]. "," .$result[$i]["middle_name"]. "," .$result[$i]["last_name"]. "," .$result[$i]["email"]. "," .$result[$i]["shipment_name"]. "," .$result[$i]["payment_name"]. "," .$result[$i]["created_on"]. "," .$result[$i]["modified_on"]. "," .$result[$i]["order_status"]. "," .$result[$i]["order_total"]. "," .$result[$i]["virtuemart_order_id"]. "\n";

}

Header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
Header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
Header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pedidos.csv');

}
```

The $result variable comes from here:

```
public function get_orders_k() {

$db=JFactory::getDBO();

    $query = " select o.order_number, o.virtuemart_order_id, o.order_total, o.order_status, o.created_on, o.modified_on, u.first_name,u.middle_name,u.last_name "
    .',u.email, pm.payment_name, vsxlang.shipment_name ' .
    $from = $this->getOrdersListQuery();

$db->setQuery($query);

$result=$db->loadAssocList();

    if ( $result > 0 )
    {
        $datos = VirtueMartModelKiala::export_to_csv($result);

    }else return 0;
}
```

Im not sure even where to start looking. I have look over the internet on various ways of doing this and tried all of them and still can't manage to get it working. Please help me out!

-Thanks

Comment: So what happens instead? Error messages? Does the file display in the browser instead? Does the file download but is broken?

Comment: The file doesnt download and when I use Firefox for example and use the Firebug to see what the button does I get this error: 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Put this code below your loop.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pedidos.csv"');

echo $shtml;
```

How did you find out the content type application/force-download? I've never heard of it. The proper MIME type for CSV is **text/csv**

You can find more examples how to use header function in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

You need also display `$shtml` you didn't do it in your code.

Comment: You mean put the headers right after the for or after the $shtml = $shtml.$result[$i].. ?

-Thanks

Comment: Headers should be sent before any other data is sent to browser. Even white character can break the script.

Answer (score 5):

Well. you may try this, it'll work if your result is not empty

```
public function export_to_csv($result)
{
    if(!$result) return false;
    ob_end_clean();
    header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
    header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=pedidos.csv');
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $headrow = $result[0];
    fputcsv($fp, array_keys($headrow));
    foreach ($result as $data) {
        fputcsv($fp, $data);
    }
    fclose($fp);
    $contLength = ob_get_length();
    header( 'Content-Length: '.$contLength);
}
```

Comment: `header( 'Content-Length: '.$contLength);` will raise an error that headers already sent.

Answer (score 3):

you need to `echo` your content after the header

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pedidos.csv');
echo $shtml
```