# File is not being downloaded when requested through Ajax using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file, csv

I need to download a .CSV file with certain information from a website, so I'm using a link and some Javascript/JQuery to get the table from the servr and create the file.

I have this link that is supposed to download the file when clicked:
`<a class="areaSummaryExport" value="1">...</a>`

And then I have this in a JS file:

This adds the click listener to the link:

```
$('.areaSummaryExport').on('click', function(){
    exportAreaSummary($(this).attr('value'), $(this));
});
```

This function gets the table from the server using an ajax request and sends it to the corresponding function to process:

```
function exportAreaSummary(selected, sender){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin_ajax.php',
        method: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {action: 'exportAreaSummary', area: selected}
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log('done');
        exportTableToCSV.apply(sender, [$($(data.table)[0]), data.name, data.header]);
    }).error(function(XMLHttpRequest){
        console.log('error');
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
    });
}
```

Finally this function adds the `href` attribute to the link with the information of the file to download:

```
function exportTableToCSV($table, filename, header) {
    console.log('printing');
    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)'),

        // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
        // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

        // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
        colDelim = '","',
        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

        // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
        csv = '"' + 'sep=,' + rowDelim +
        (header? header.join(colDelim) + rowDelim : '') +
        $rows.map(function (i, row) {
            var $row = $(row),
                $cols = $row.find('td, th');

            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    text = $col.text();

                return text.replace(/"/g, '""'); // escape double quotes

            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

        // Data URI
        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
    $(this)
        .attr({
        'download': filename,
            'href': csvData,
            'target': '_blank'
    });
    console.log('printed');
}
```

The problem is that it gets the info for the CSV file and adds it in the `href` attribute in the link, but it won't download the file (I have to click again for it to work).

I know the last function works because I use it somewhere else, but there I already have the table on the screen so there's no ajax involved. So I'm guessing the problem is with the ajax, but not sure where.

I also tried firing the click event through JS but it doesn't work either.

Comment: of course when you click first time its appending href, from that time onwards only it would download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you create the CSV at server side PHP program and set Content-Type as "application/vnd.ms-excel" (or) "text/csv" and set "Content-Disposition: attachment; [yourfilename] "

Refer this [Create a CSV File for a user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217424/create-a-csv-file-for-a-user-in-php)

Refer this [Force Download CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269568/force-download-csv-file)

Simply put hyperlink as

```
<a class="areaSummaryExport" href="admin_ajax.php" value="1">...</a>
```

Comment: I tried that before, but don't quite understand how to do it. I created a new php file, send a request and in the php I `echo`ed the content I want in the CSV. Now im `console.log`ging it and I see no file.. What should I do different?

Comment: Don't do coding in ajax, simply leave the hyperlink with href="download.php" as it is. it will download, if you want help, invite me in chat