# downloading a file from s3 with laravel storage

Tags: laravel

I have a button that creates and csv , i want it to a return a trigger to download the file to the user.
currently i'm getting the file content as the response data.
in my controller i use:

```php
Storage::put($filepath, $fileconent);
$headers = [
      'Content-Type' => 'Content-Type: text/csv',
 ];
return Storage::download($filepath, $filename, $headers ); 

(Storage::download adds the 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename' header)
```

what am i missing?
thanks

Comment: Welcome SO... What error u r getting.?

Comment: thanks. im not getting any error, i'm actually getting status code 200.  its just that the file content appears in the response data instead of triggering download.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force Download CSV File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269568/force-download-csv-file)

Comment: no :( still same result

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
  $file =  Storage::disk('s3')->get($file_path);

  $headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'your_content_type', 
    'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
    'Content-Disposition' => "attachment; filename={$yourFileName}",
    'filename'=> $yourFileName
 ];

return response($file, 200, $headers);
```

Comment: thanks, still shows content in response data and doesn't trigger a download...